# How to force detection of PS/2 mouse in multi-media Windows environment?

Tags: windows-vista, mouse, tuner-card, input-device, device-manager

Windows now thinks that I have some sort of infrared mouse hooked up to my new TV Tuner (mouse properties show "human input device on eHome infrared" something or another).

How can I dissuade it of this crazy idea and force it to detect my regular old PS/2 mouse?

Answer (score 0):

Try poking around settings for your TV card. It is probably detecting its remote control device as a mouse. You may have to disable the remote control or to get newer drivers for it. I have same problem, but mine is detected as a keyboard.